# How can I use machine learning to predict failure in system log file?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, rule-engine, bigdata

I work on a project which have as a principal purpose A creation of a prediction system failures in servers which is based on analyzing the log file. In addition to that  I have to use some  algorithms as Rules engines and deep learning. For the moment I do not know exactly from which track  to start, and if these  algorithms  are the best one  to use. I would be grateful for any help or proposals.

Answer (score -1):

There a good number of algorithms you can use. I'll personally suggest SVM.
Here a nice paper does exactly what you are asking for

https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/wasl08/tech/full_papers/fulp/fulp.pdf

Comment: The user specifically asked specifically for Rule Learning and Deep Learning. Furthermore, your answer is kind-of-a "link only answer".... 
(If I wouldn't be to lazy I would down vote your answer, please improve!)